# StartupNextInstance in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to implement StartupNextInstance for a single-instance application, to simply add a messagebox warning that the application is already running when running from code, rather than just switching to the active application w/o notice.  Currently when I start the application from code in Visual Studio and I already have the compiled version running, it switches to the compiled version and stops debugging.  I want it to be obvious that it has switched to the compiled version rather than just switching w/o any notice.

I have "Make single instance application" checked:

Project Properties:
[image: Project Properties]

and have added the following to ApplicationEvents.vb:

```
        Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
#If DEBUG Then
      MsgBox("PI is alread running.", Nothing, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
#End If
    End Sub
```

But the code in the Sub never fires.

What am I missing?

Comment: By design, it fires in the process that is already running and not in the one you're trying to debug.

Comment: If you have set it to be a single-instance application then it's always going to switch the already-running instance anyway, so why does it matter which instance displays the message? Just get rid of the conditional compilation and the original instance will display the message and the user will be notified exactly as you want. You seem to be trying to solve a problem that you created yourself.

Comment: It seems that you have some misunderstandings about single-instance applications and StartupNextInstance. It switches to a process that is already running before triggering the StartupNextInstance event.

Comment: As I said, I want the warning that the production version is running when I'm running in Debug, rather than just switching to the existing instance.

Comment: What is the point of StartupNextInstance if it is not for this particular use case?  The default comments in the ApplicationEvents.vb say "' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just reread and finally get @Hans Passant's comment.  It doesn't fire in the second instance, only the first/existing instance.  Doh!